# Saw this on interview questionaire. Any thoughts?

Tags: syntax, logic

--- code begins below this line ---

A: THINK a program::

B: THINK by James Requenez::

C: CUP one IS "Hello World"::

D: CUP two IS "What year were you born?"::

E: CUP three IS "Enter first value"::

F: CUP four IS "Enter second value"::

G: CUP five IS “two”

H: CUP six IS ::

I:::

J: SNIFF five::

K:            SMELL "one" SPIT one:>

L:                   JUMP Z::

M:            SMELL "two" SPIT two:>

N:                   SIP apple:>

O:                   SPIT CHEW NOW SLICE apple SEW "years old":>

P:                   JUMP Y::

Q:            SMELL "three" SPIT three:>

R:                   SIP banana:>

S:                   SPIT four:>

T:                   SIP carrot:>

U:                   SPIT CHEW banana SEW carrot:>

V:                   JUMP Z::

W:            SMELL "four" SPIT four:>

X:                   SIP daiquiri::

Y: SPIT "thank you"::

Z: SPIT "bye"::

::::

--- end of code snippet above this line

- Can you explain what this code does, and what is the output if any?
- Can you identify a syntax bug?
- Can you identify a logic bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my guess:

```
the program prints "What year were you born?"
then reads the value in variable apple
then prints (current year - apple) "year old"
then prints "thank you"
then prints "bye"
and terminates
```

The syntax error is in line G (missing :: at end of line)

The logical error is line W (write "Enter second value" without having written "Enter first value").

These are the commands:

THINK - comment

CUP x IS y - bind x to y

SNIFF - case

SMELL - one case test

JUMP - jump

SIP x - read from input stream to a variable x

x SLICE y - (x - y)

CHEW x SEW y - x || y